# basic probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the difference between joint probability $P(X,Y)$ and the probability of $P(X)P(Y)$?

Answer (score 2):

The second one is the product of two probabilities:

Suppose you toss a coin two consecutive times. Let $X,\,Y$ be random variables defined as:

$X:=$"Number of tails obtained"
$Y:=$"Number of heads obtained"

We know that $\displaystyle P(X=0)=\binom{2}{0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=P(Y=0).$ However $P(X=0,Y=0)=0.$

This is: the probability of obtaining no tails in the two tosses is $1/4$. But of course, in two tosses you can't get $0$ heads and $0$ tails.

So the difference is that when you talk about joint probability, you are looking for the probability of $X$ and $Y$ happening at the same time, whilst $P(X)P(Y)$ is just the multiplication of the probabilities of each random variable.

Comment: Can you please give me an additional example so I can visualize it better?

Comment: Read the last sentence I wrote carefully. Try to give yourself that additional example. Think for example of throwing 2 dices at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

$P(X, Y) = P(X \cap Y) \quad \quad$ (It is the probability that X and Y occur together)
If X and Y are independent, then $P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y)$
If X and Y are not independent, then $P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y | X)$

For example, suppose we have a box containing 2 Red and 3 Blue balls.
Suppose we draw 2 balls.
Let X be the event that a red ball is drawn on the first draw.
Let Y be the event that a red ball is drawn on the second draw.

If we draw with replacement, then X and Y are independent.
That is, the probability of a red ball being drawn is the same on both draws.
So, $P(X) = P(Y) = \frac{2}{5}$
Then, $P(X, Y) = P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y)=(\frac{2}{5})(\frac{2}{5})$

Now, suppose we draw without replacing the balls. This means X and Y are not independent.
Then the probability of drawing a red ball on the second draw depends on what ball we drew on the first draw.
Then, $P(X, Y) = P(X \cap Y)=P(X)P(Y | X) = (\frac{2}{5})(\frac{1}{4})$

because after drawing a red ball on the first draw, there are 1 red and 3 blue balls left in the box. So, the probability of drawing a red on the second draw is $\frac{1}{4}$

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not 100% clear from the question but everything indicates that X and Y should be *random variables* here, not events.